# Counting the number each element in a comma seperated column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to using `Tableau`.I want to count the number of times each genre appears in the data set.

In the data set(image attached), I have several genres for one show. I want to count the number of each genre in the data set and display it in Tableau

[image: Data set]

Comment: can you share dataset

Comment: I am really sorry, I dont think i will be able to share the data set :(

Comment: do you have access to database?

Comment: I do have the access to the database but i am afraid i wont be able to share the data. may be i will create a similar fake data set and provide it to you?

Comment: No not a problem of data... I have a wayout for your problem

Comment: Check answer....

Comment: If you are still confused, then create a sample fake data, will develop the workbook and share with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to database, then take the dump of data in a excel.

Split the data by `,` and then create a individual column for every word in the genre column.

Now take the excel as source to tableau, In tableau pivot the splitted columns of Genre.

Go to sheet in tableau, Place the pivot field values in rows and count of pivot field values as measures.

You should be able to see the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by an alternative method if you know the distinct list of all genre.

what you need to do is to create a separate calculative field for each Genre using

```
if contains(Genre,'action') then 1 else 0 end
```

and then use the Sum of these field as the count of Series per genre.

I know this is a hideous task but, it can be done if you do not have any other option.